# why is the solution to $x^2 = 3$ the same as $x = \pm \sqrt 3$

Tags: logic, polynomials

I understand that in order to simplify $x$ in this equation:
$x^2 = 3$ we would need to get the square root  on both sides what i dont understand is the fact that it is written as $x = \pm \sqrt 3$.
I don't understand where the $±$ comes from  , this problem was a part of solving polynomials by factoring and I just want the reasoning behind why it wouldn't simply be $x = \sqrt 3$ but $x = x = \pm \sqrt 3$.

the original equation :
$2x^5+12x^3 -54x = 0$

my solutions :

$x=0 $
$x=\pm \sqrt 3$
$x = \pm 3i$

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Suppose you drew the equation of a parabola $y=x^2-3$: it would be an upward pointing parabola with a minimum at $(0,-3)$.  Suppose from your diagram you had to estimate the values of $x$ for which $y=0$.  Since the curve crosses the $x$-axis (i.e. the line $y=0$) at two points, it is reasonable to say that there are two solutions to $x^2-3=0$, i.e. to $x^2=3$, and that they are symmetric across the $y$-axis, i.e. one is the negative of the other

Comment: Because both $\sqrt{3}$ and $-\sqrt{3}$ square to 3, so both are valid solutions — plug them back into the original equation and you’ll see

Comment: The  very definition of $\sqrt a$ is that it is the non-negative number $x$ such that $x^2=a$, so your question is meaningless. Whether it exists and is unique is another problem.

Comment: You need more than one solution because there is more than one solution. "$x=\pm\sqrt{3}$" is simply shorthand for "$x=\sqrt{3}$ or $x=-\sqrt{3}$".

Comment: $x^2-3 = (x-\sqrt 3)(x+\sqrt 3)$ so these are the only roots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you can square either $-\sqrt3$ or $\sqrt3$ to get $3$ and the question requires you to find a real/complex number that can be squared to give $3$ as the answer.

Comment: now i see , x^2 = 3 the square root of 3 is either 2 negatives or 2 positives

Answer (score 1):

It comes from the identity $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$. Now, solve $|x|=\sqrt{3}$. 
Also, $x^2=3$; $x^2-3=0$; $(x-\sqrt{3})(x+\sqrt{3})=0$

Comment: ok this shows a good explanation aswell , u factored x^2 = 3 to show the reasoning

Comment: @RonComputing: A lot of people miss this concept: square root of  $x^2$ is the absolute value of $x$. This is because the square root is always positive, it cannot be $x$ if $x<0$

Answer (score 0):

We are looking for $x$ such that

$$x^2 = 3$$

and since both $x=\sqrt 3$ and $x=-\sqrt 3$ satisfy the equation, these are the two roots for the given equation.